# New layout is taking too much space. Is there option to minimize the left side bar?

Tags: support, left-navigation

I am kind of feeling annoyed with the new sidebar. It's taking a large portion of space of the window and the actual contents are minimized in font size to read smoothly as before. Should that sidebar menu not be made collapsible or some kind of button to minimize? Is there any option already?
[image]

Comment: Even if you minimize the left sidebar (which is absolutely an option), with your screen width, all it will do is give you *more* white space. The center section in your screenshot looks like it's already at the max width.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Under the settings for your profile you can find the option to hide it.
[image]

Comment: I wish this came disabled by default or a close button in the sidebar itself. It's not obvious for new users and forcing a new design like that kinda sucks.

Comment: @SushiHangover then you should post a bug report on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness?cb=1) post.

Comment: @SushiHangover just FYI, there are separate settings for Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Meta. Make sure it's disabled in both sites.

Comment: ANNNNND GONE!!! That was hideous. I have my font size magnified, so I can read SO on my secodary monitor, which is slightly further away to my right, and has a smaller physical screen size than my main one.  The sizing is just perfect, then this THING, comes out of no-where, and pushed everything off to the right, it needs to be off by default.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Absolutely correct, Thank you... I ***assumed*** site-wide, but : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness?cb=1#comment1016694_310908

Comment: Not having a toggle to show/hide on the menu itself is one of the weirdest decisions I've seen. That and the content itself, which is why we're all here, continues to lose real estate. SO caps their container at `1264px`. Why not use the whitespace?

Answer (score 3):

You can also scroll down to the bottom of each page and select "Disable Responsiveness".

This will also remove the left part.

Comment: Selecting that doesn't change anything about the left side bar for me. It just makes the right hand side of page get cut off when the window is narrow.